# Conversion to float with variable number of decimal places Obj-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have a requirement in app that we need variable number of decimal places for a field, rule for number of decimal places is returned from web service and user can change that rule from web portal

suppose `float number = 125.879601223`

what i need, if

```
int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 4
NSString *convertedString = @"125.8796"
```

or,

```
int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 2
NSString *convertedString = @"125.87"
```

Need a way to convert string based on `numberOfDecimalPlaces` rule, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *patternStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%0.%df", numberOfDecimalPlaces];
NSString *convertedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:patternStr, number];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:numberOfDecimalPlaces];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

NSString * convertedString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: number]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `*` modifier in the string format:

```
NSString *convertedString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.*f", numberOfDecimalPlaces, number];
```